# I have 4 days before I leave to got to Peru. Typhoid Shot or Pills?

Tags: health, peru

I had no idea until recently that it is recommended that I have the Typhoid Vaccine. I have a had trouble finding it, but now that I have, I only have 4 days until my trip. If I get it today, will it still be worth it? If so, what would work better with such a short notice, the shot or the 7 day pills?

Comment: Speak to a medical professional, but I'd imagine that they'd recommend the injection, as it works off one go and doesn't need you to keep the medication chilled for the next week or two.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking about details of a medication, not travel.

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to take the shot, because the pills need to be taken on alternate days and there are 3 or 4 pills to take. The pills need to be stored in a refrigerator, so bringing them with you to complete the course may be difficult.

Comment: All 4 pills are also supposed to be completed at least 1 week before traveling to an area where there is a risk for typhoid.